# Использование $rootScope в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Хотел бы задать небольшой вопрос, по поводу **AngularJS**, касательно использования `$rootScope`. 
Слышал, что помещать в скоуп нужно только то, что непосредственно используется в представлении. А я в `$rootScope` поместил функцию для того, чтобы она была доступна двум контроллерам, которые никак между собой не связаны с целью не дублировать один и тот же код.

Так вот хотел бы узнать насколько такое использование допустимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Засорять $rootScope допустимо, но не рекомендуется. Для того, чтобы не дублировать код, нужно создавать сервисы и загружать их по мере необходимости. Также сервисы можно использовать, чтобы расшаривать данные между контролерами, которые могут находиться далеко друг от друга.

Comment: Спасибо, но есть ли смысл использовать сервис для одной единственной функции, состоящей из 6 строк?

Comment: С моей точки зрения - имеет. В первую очередь, потому что $rootScope - это не выгребная яма. Нет никаких ограничений, что туда класть, но Вы как разработчик должны ограничивать себя от этого. Во-вторых, это более удобно для последующей поддержки системы.
Собственно тут можно до бесконечности перечислять плюсы модульности, ограничусь лишь тем что сказал.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо еще раз за ответ!